# Unity launcher, dash and menu fonts are not anti-aliased

Tags: unity, launcher, fonts, qt

I am running Ubuntu 14.04. After installing Qt4 settings manager and tinkering with it (changing the font face for Qt apps) I notice that unity launcher, dash and menu and date indicator fonts are not anti-aliased anymore. I have no idea why that happened. Any ideas why? See the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The screenshots itself are very blurry to distinguish a blurry or not blurry text.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to insert links to externally hosted images, but it resized them to embed in the message, so... I mean, the fonts have medium or full hinting, whereas in unity settings I see 'slight'. And in fact slight hinting is used everywhere - in apps, terminal, logout menu etc. But in Files manager, the apps menu fonts are medium hinted.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a really old post, I thought of leaving the solution I found after searching for quite a while.

Set the Text Scaling Factor to something different from 1.0 (1.01 worked for me) and leave Antialiasing set to Rgba. I did this using the unity-tweak-tool.